# show hide image script after 4 seconds

Tags: images, jquery, javascript

On my homepage I need a javascript/jQuery script to show our site logo image and close it after 5 seconds. Only when user visits the first time our site. No mouseover or clicks needed. Complete automatic.

Seen several parts of scripts here on stackexchange, but not what I described here above. Also not included with a certain image.

This is the image: rdp_banner.jpg

Maybe there is someone who can help me, I hope.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had for example,

```
<img src="rdp_banner.jpg" id="logoimage">
```

You could just do...

```
add_action('init','checkvisitcookie');
function checkvisitcookie() {
    if (isset($_COOKIE['firsttimevisit'])) {return;}
    setCookie('firsttimevisit','1',100*365*24*60*60);  
    add_action('wp_footer','fadelogoout');
} 

function fadelogoout() {
    echo "<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery('#logoimage').fadeOut();
        }, 5000);
    });
    </script>";
}
```

Just to make it almost relevant to WordPress ;-)

Comment: A cookie is very useful here.

Comment: for an off-topic post? ok may as well, guess i did answer it didn't i...

Comment: 100 years should be sufficient right? :-P

Comment: Nicely done @majick (y). You had my up-vote.

Comment: I added the script code in functions.php How to start this function? With [fadelogoout] or with [wp_footer]? <img> block added on homepage. But the image shown constant not only for 5 seconds.

Comment: no as you asked it will work automatically... but you need to make sure the image id matches the image, if not you may need to add one. if you add your actual image element code to your question it would help.

Comment: This I added on homepage: <img src="http://aff.norus.nl/wp-content/uploads/RdPLogo_final_645.jpg" id="logoimage"> and image is correct shown only not closed after 5 sec.

Comment: should be fine, don't forget to clear your cookies while testing

Comment: I believe you but I tested it with FF Chrome Edge. First clear history including cache and then running http://aff.norus.nl/
Result: image stays on screen. I have no idea what I do wrong. Also on my Tablet same result, not hiding image. Suggestions?

Comment: yes I missed a `);`, see updated code

Comment: It works great! Thanks and also for your patient ;)

Comment: no problems, had a bit of fun with it :)